# Effects of upgrading MongoDB server tiers

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, cpu, ram

I have an AWS ec2 server that is running an application that is connected to a MongoDB atlas sharded cluster. Periodically, the application will slow down and I will receive alerts from MongoDB about high CPU steal %. I am looking to upgrade my MongoDB server tier and see the only difference in the options is more storage space and more RAM, but the number of vCPUs is the same. I'm wondering if anyone has any insight on whether this increased RAM will help with the CPU steal % alerts I am receiving and whether it will help speed up the app? Otherwise, am I better off upgrading my AWS server tier for more CPU that way?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think more RAM will necessarily help if you're mostly CPU Bound.  However, if you're using MongoAtlas then the alternative tiers definitely do provide more vCPU as you go up the scaling options.

You can also enable auto scaling and set your minimum and maximum tiers to allow the database to scale as necessary: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/cluster-autoscaling/

However, be warned that MongoAtlas has a pretty aggressive scale-out and a pretty crappy scale-in. I think the scale-in only happens after 24hours so it can get costly.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, alternative tiers do give more vCPU but I'd rather not go that high up for my application (Maximum I would get is M30). I also don't want to set autoscaling because of the aggressive scale-out and crappy scale-in as you mentioned. This may be a stupid question but just to be sure, upgrading the CPU on my aws ec2 instance won't have any effect on the vCPU from mongo right?

Comment: Yes that's right. Your EC2 instance is isolated from MongoAtlas so increasing the vCPU there won't have any tangible affect.  

If you don't want to upgrade beyond an M30 then you could look inwardly. What is the workload that is being run on the database? Is it possible for the workload to be queued up? Are there efficiency improvements like indexes that could be added to alleviate some of the strain.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! Most likely there are some improvements like indexes that can be added but I was hoping for an easier solution from upgrading hahaha. I have no issue with the current workload being done it doesn't have any terrible effects on the app when it runs high, I just don't like the alerts saying CPU steal % has gone high so was wondering what could be done to stop that. Seems like M30+ uses dedicated vCPU which means there's no chance for steal % running up, so that may be the way to go. Thanks for the responses though, really appreciate it!